# User Interface Design Package

Tags: user-interface, uml, frontend, modeling

I am working on designing a user interface and want to convey my design to my peers. Typically, I'd use a mock-up of the UI and UML, but given the complexity, size, and multiple asynchronous interactions I'm not sure that this makes the most sense. It doesn't seem to allow to efficiently describe the process.

Does anyone have experience in designing large User Interface's? How would a company that designs UI's go about modeling their process/ design? This seems to be a question for the 'front-end' engineers.

Answer (score 0):

well let's go for an answer even if your question is very large. I'll give you my experience and hope it will help you to decide.

To my mind, using UML in a project is very useful if you use it right, it's often clear, quite easy to understand. On the other side, when working on huge project, it's sometimes costly because it takes time to create your diagrams and nowadays, you have to be as fast as possible !

These last months I have worked on a project with a GUI and to well define it, I have first draw some screen on paper and quickly ask for some drawbacks near the coffee machine. 
I have created some activity diagrams and then, created a mock-up.

**How to choose now ?**

First of all, if your GUI should have a beautiful design, I don't think you can avoid a mock-up, but I'm don't know if it's your goal.

My main tip would be, try to simplify your complexity in your program. If you have multiple asynchronous that could arise everytime/everywhere, you'll encounter a lot a problem.

In my project, let's say my tablet could be preempted by an external computer whenever/wherever. I just have created a class beforehand to manage this asynchronous call but my sub-activity-diagrams stayed intact.

Draw specific diagram for specific functionalities and leave useless diagrams which are not relevant/too simple.

Hard to explain you more than this without giving you any example. Hope it will help a bit.